# How to add conditions to update an entry with entity framework linq-to-entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Suppose I have the following entities:

```
public class Library
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }

    public Library()
    {
        Books = new HashSet<Book>();
    }
}
public class Book
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int LibraryID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublicationDate { get; set; }
    public bool CheckedOut { get; set; }
}
```

There are a bunch of libraries, and each library has a bunch of books. Someone at the library with ID=1 checks out the book with ID=42, so I want to update the `CheckedOut` property to true. Suppose for whatever reason I already know the library ID and book ID but not the other info. I can update just the `CheckedOut` property fairly easily without fetching all the book data from the database:

```
Book book=new Book(){
    ID=42,
    LibraryID=1,
    CheckedOut=true
}
context.Books.Attach(book);
var entry=context.Entry(book);
entry.Property(b=>b.CheckedOut).IsModified=true;
context.SaveChanges();
```

Here's my question. How can I also force it to fail if the `LibraryID` in the database is not `1` for this book? In plain SQL I could write

```
UPDATE Books SET CheckedOut=1 WHERE ID=42 AND LibraryID=1
```

How do I do the same thing with entity framework?

An obvious use case here is to add more security--for example, if the user does not have the authority to check out a book from any library other than 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `.Attach(book)`, you are actually telling EF: hey, these are the **original** values of the existing record in the database. So in your case EF will think that the existing `book.LibraryID` is `1`. You can utilize that fact and force the EF to perform the desired check by configuring `LibraryID` property to be used as [Optimistic Concurrency Token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#1.12) by either Data Annotations:

```
public class Book
{
    // ...
    [ConcurrencyCheck]
    public int LibraryID { get; set; }
}
```

or Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Book>()
    .Property(e => e.LibraryID).IsConcurrencyToken();
```

Now if you turn EF logging on and execute you snippet, you'll see something like this:

Opened connection at 14/10/2016 21:35:32 +03:00

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Books]
SET [CheckedOut] = @0
WHERE (([ID] = @1) AND ([LibraryID] = @2))

-- @0: 'True' (Type = Boolean)

-- @1: '42' (Type = Int32)

-- @2: '1' (Type = Int32)
```

which is similar to what you are after.

The only potential issue with this approach is that you'll get `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` when the `LibraryID` in the database is not `1`.