# EF: Update without Select with condition

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'd like to update a record in a db by Entity Framework Core by using one SQL UPDATE call only with a condition saying the record is not deleted.

This code represents what I want to do, but invoke 2 db calls (select+update):

```
  var book = await context.Books.Where(b => b.Id == bookId && !m.Deleted).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
  if (usr == null) return null;

  book.ReturnDate = DateTime.Now;

  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This code is better: only one db call, but does not include the !m.Deleted condition (and null check?).

```
  var book = new Book() {
      Id = bookId,
      ReturnDate = DateTime.Now
  };

  this.context.Books.Attach(book);
  this.context.Entry(book).Property(p => p.ReturnDate).IsModified = true;
  await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

How is it possible to write it in EF Core, so it would generate just one UPDATE call? Something like this one:

```
UPDATE Books SET ReturnDate = GetDate() WHERE Id = BookId AND Deleted = 0
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048825/how-to-add-conditions-to-update-an-entry-with-entity-framework-linq-to-entities

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add conditions to update an entry with entity framework linq-to-entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40048825/how-to-add-conditions-to-update-an-entry-with-entity-framework-linq-to-entities)

Comment: The [ConcurrencyCheck] instructs EF to include the property in UPDATE in WHERE part. This is good. However it throws an exception when the condition is not met.

Comment: Do you think the IsConcurrencyToken can commonly be used to form the where condition in UPDATE? I think more it's just a workaround.